# Does the following trade history constitute a wash sale

Tags: wash-sale

1. 2/17/21 bought 100 shares of FTFT at $9 a share
2. 2/18/21 bought 100 shares of FTFT at $9 a share
3. 2/25/21 bought 100 shares of FTFT at $5.45 a share.
4. 12/1/21 bought 200 shares of FTFT at $1.50 a share.
5. 12/3/21 sold FIFO 300 shares at $1.25

I am in Pennsylvania, USA

Can the above sale trigger wash sale?

Comment: Is there something specific in your scenario that you think would make this not a wash sale? If you tell us what you are thinking, we can better address your concerns.

Comment: Did your sale at a loss occur within 30 days before or after your last purchase? Look at your scenario and tell me what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. A wash sale occurs when a sale (at a loss, of course) has a purchase +/- 30 days of that sale. The loss from the first 200 shares is disallowed, and added to your basis for the 200 shares you bought 12/1.

I assume this was done in a taxable, non-retirement account.